# Swift- Copying plist just writing location into file?

Tags: swift

I am trying to copy a plist file from my app to the documents folder- and it does- except instead of copying the contents of the file, it just does this: [image]

It literally just copies the destination directory into the file -_- Here is my code:

```
var documentsDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString

var path : NSString = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("HiddenSettings.plist")
var fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
if (!(fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(path)))
{
    var bundle : NSString = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("HiddenSettings", ofType: "plist")!
    NSLog(bundle+" -> "+path)
    fileManager.copyItemAtPath(bundle, toPath: path, error:nil)
}
```

Why does it do this?

Comment: The code works for me. What is the actual content of hiddenplist?

Comment: @rakeshbs Just a boolean called FirstLaunch set to YES.

Answer (score 0):

Try running it again after resetting Content and Settings of the simulator. 
Go to iOS Simulator menu in the Simulator app and choose **Reset Content and Settings**.

Try logging error like this

```
var error:NSError?
fileManager.copyItemAtPath(bundle, toPath: path, error:&error)
println(error)
```

Comment: No dice, still same result.

Comment: did it enter the condition and log the output after you reset? the same code is working for me.

Comment: Yes it did, I even tried it on my phone with iFile to check the document and it did the same thing.

Comment: Latest XCode 6 from the appstore.

Comment: did u try logging the error argument. check my updated answer?

Comment: It's nil. This is weird. I'll be right back, I need to restart my computer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68260/discussion-between-user3042719-and-rakeshbs).